# Django Mixin, Python Inheritance behaviour - Returning old values for multiple classes

Tags: python, django

I wanted to clarify a behavior in python

Here's a snippet written in django

```
from django.shortcuts import render

from django.views.generic import CreateView, UpdateView, TemplateView

from testapp.models import TestCategory

# Create your views here.
class xMixin:
    urlVal = {}


    def get_someval(self):
        return self.urlVal

    def get_value(self):
        return self.get_someval()

class TestCategoryCreateView(xMixin, TemplateView):
    model = TestCategory
    template_name = "test_cat.html"

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context["urlv"] = self.get_value()
        return context
    


class TestCategoryUpdateView(xMixin, TemplateView):
    model = TestCategory
    template_name = "test_cat.html"

    def get_someval(self):
        urlval = super().get_someval()
        urlval['123'] = 'abc'
        return urlval

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context["urlv"] = self.get_value()
        return context
```

I was expecting the context["urlv"] getting their respective values..

for TestCategoryUpdateView, it should be { '123': 'abc' } and

for TestCategoryCreateView, it should be {}

But, when i do the following steps, it results differently

1. Visit create view url -> urlv is {}
2. Visit update view url -> urlv is { '123' : 'abc' }
3. Visit create view url again -> urlv is { '123' : 'abc' }
4. Visit create view url anytime from this point -> urlv is { '123' : 'abc' }

What would be a good way to avoid this behaviour ?

Comment: Please see how to create a [mre]. Your given example has other problems than what you state, for starters `return get_someval()` will give an error, next you declare `someVal` but use `urlVal`...

Comment: The problem though is that you forget that dictionaries are _mutable_, and the fact that returning some object will not magically create a copy of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forget that dictionaries are [*mutable* objects](https://www.google.com/search?q=python+mutable+objects), i.e. their values can be changed. When you write:

```
return self.urlVal
```

You are returning the same object and not a *copy* of the object, hence later when a function modifies it, (i.e. `urlval['123'] = 'abc'`) it is modifying the *original* dictionary. You can solve this problem by updating / unpacking the dictionary to create a copy:

```
class TestCategoryUpdateView(xMixin, TemplateView):
    model = TestCategory
    template_name = "test_cat.html"

    def get_someval(self):
        urlval = super().get_someval()
        urlval = {**urlval}  # copying the dictionary
        urlval['123'] = 'abc'
        return urlval

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context["urlv"] = self.get_value()
        return context
```

---

> **Note**: Your code style (set an empty dictionary as an attribute, make *two* methods just to return its value, etc.) looks bad to me but
> that may be because you have tried to make a smaller example. But if
> it *is* as you show, then you should reconsider your code, you can
> write it to be much simpler.

Comment: Thanks, i just wrote a simple example referring to django's style of writing mixin github.com/django/django/blob/main/django/views/generic/edit.py . returning dict.copy() should also work right ?

Comment: @AdharshM Ah I see you copied from `FormMixin`, yes you can use `dict.copy()`.